# button settext to next class

Tags: android, button, settext

I have two classes; the `first.class` and `second.class`. On my `first.class` there is a button and on my `second.class` there is no button. I need it so when the button from the `first.class` is clicked there will be a text that will appear on the `second.class` with an option to save it.

**first.class**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override   
   public void onClick(View v) {


}
});
```

Comment: But, what text will be there? Means will you get it dynamically from your first activity or by default text is there?

Comment: default text is there how can i code that?

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override   
   public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent p = new Intent(first.this,
                         second.class);
     startActivity(p);


}

});
```

and then in second class load a xml file containing textview

```
package ......;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import dolphin.devlopers.com.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

public class gmail1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second); //the file which contains textview and ui

        TextView  tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  }
```

Manifest file:

```
<Activity 
  android:name="first">
</Activity>

<Activity 
  android:name="second">
</Activity>
```

second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hi"
       />

</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: make  second.xml in layout folder

Comment: what i mean is. if i click the  button in the first.class there will be a settext that will show in the second.class

Answer (score 0):

```
public class first{
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override   
   public void onClick(View v) {

    second.setText(text);
}
});
}
```

---

```
public class second{
private static String textFromFirst;

public static void setText(String text){
second.textFromFirst = text;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear.

When you say `first.class` and `second.class`, do you mean they both extends `Activity`?
 Meaning, they are two different "Screens" in your app, and clicking the button on the `first` activity would launch the `second` and change its text? if so, You can use intents to pass info between activities. Something like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override   
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(first.this, second.class);

        // NOW COMES THE IMPORTANT PART, Put the text you want to be passed
        intent.putExtra("text_identifier", "The text to show"); 

        startActivity(intent);
    }

});
```

and in Second.java:

```
private TextView tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    // Retreive the text you sent eralier
    String theText = getIntent().getStringExtra("text_identifier");
    tv.setText(theText);
    // Do any extra onCreate things
}
```

If it's not what you're after, let me know and I'll see what I can think off, but please try to explain a bit better

Good luck!

Comment: yes you get my point tahnk you very much for your answer. but i have an error in  intent.putExtra("text_identifier, "The text to show"); 

                   startActivity(intent);

Comment: What error are you getting? This piece of code is copy & paste from a working code of mine (I noticed there were missing end quotes in the line you posted)

Comment: Also, If you found this answer (or any other) helpful, please up vote (the up button to the left of the question), and if you found it correct for your question, please accept it (the check mark in the same place) Welcom to SO

Answer (score 0):

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="57dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:text="Click" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Second.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

### second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### Second.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Second extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}


    @Override
      public void onResume()
      {
          super.onResume();
          tv.setText("Hello");

      }
}
```

### manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.f"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.f.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Second" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: why resume? newbie question

Comment: I have put it because every time your activity starts, by default that message will be there. If u want to set it dynamically then you have to get it from user, and in that case this will not be the case.

Comment: what if i want that the tv.setText("Hello"); is coming from the button from the first class?is that possible?  everytime i will click the button in the first class there will  be hello even i intent it in othere classes

Comment: one more thing how can i make it without implementing a textview. i mean is it will automatically make a textview for the settext

Comment: yes im new. hehehe. do i really need to make a textview to my xml so that the text will show to me? is there any code that will make a textview and the text if i cllick the button?

Comment: for that you have to create text view dynamically...for that you have to deal with java...Can't v talk in chat?

Comment: @nice...hey if u have any difficulties then u can tell me

Comment: the reason why im asking this question is because i have an android app game that has a highscore and i want to  have a button save that will settext the score to the highscore.class which is the second.class. do you have an gmail can we chat?